# hudson build if changed from last build

Tags: hudson

I wanted to know if there is a way that hudson will start a build and stop it if nothing was changed?

Because I have a script after the build which I don't want to run if nothing has changed from least build(only if someone checked in a file for example).

Answer (score 8):

In a job configuration, you can select the type of trigger that will start the build. Among them, you can:

- ask Hudson to build periodically (for example every hour, every night...), even if no changes have been commited. This is the option *Build periodically*.
- ask Hudson to **check** periodically the CVS/SVN/..., and if there are changes since the last build, then it will start the build. This is the option *Pool SCM*

The second option is what you are looking for, I suppose...

**Edit**, regarding the comments...

ClearCase is not supported natively by Hudson. A [plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/ClearCase+Plugin) is therefore needed to use the ClearCase SCM. However, it seems that this plugin does not track - yet - properly the SCM changes of a project, as stated in their todo list:

```
Add ability to perform difference report between any two builds using baseline
```

I'm not sure if this is directly related to your problem, but I think that the best solution is to contact the plugin developers team and eventually to create an issue in the [Hudson's JIRA system](https://hudson.dev.java.net/issues/)...

Comment: yes the second option is what i need but still i configured it to check every minute,then i changed a file and checked it in at clearcase,still it did not discover any change!?maybe i dont know how to use this option...

Comment: ClearCase is not supported natively by Hudson. A plugin is needed. Maybe something is not correct in this plugin, that's why Hudson does not behave as expected.
In the ClearCase plugin page, I see, in the Todolist "Add ability to perform difference report between any two builds using baseline". Maybe this explains why Hudson fails to track changes in your project...

Comment: i have the clear case plugin installed,iv'e did some builds and when i checked in i could see the update in the build,but this option of poll scm ignore this changes,btw i don't change baselines, i just want it to build after a developer checked in a file...

Comment: BTW Thanks alot for the help and wuick response.

Comment: Please mark this question as answered if your question is cleared.